# How to get Base64 string out of HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, base64

I have a div containing an image and some text. The user is able to customize it. Once his modifications are done, I would like to save the div as an image with the text on it.
Just like if he took a screenshot.

I am able to save images from Base64 strings in my PHP side but I can't get the correct Base64 from the HTML.

So, I would like to know how to get the base64 from the HTML inside my div, using JavaScript or jQuery. I could also add plugins.

Comment: That worked thanks! you should make a real answer so I can confirm it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/)

http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/examples.html

```
html2canvas($("#div"), {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
        var myImage = canvas.toDataURL("img/png");
        window.open(myImage);
    }
});
```

Comment: The next answer is correct. There is no need for canvas. This answer involving the canvas is convoluted.

Answer (score 7):

Try

```
var elem = $("div")[0].outerHTML;
var blob = new Blob([elem], {
    "type": "text/html"
});
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function (evt) {
    if (evt.target.readyState === 2) {
        console.log(
                     // full data-uri
                     evt.target.result
                     // base64 portion of data-uri
                   , evt.target.result.slice(22, evt.target.result.length));
        // window.open(evt.target.result)
    };
};
reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/9mg5sf7o/